# undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm trying to use my webcam using C++ and OpenCV, but i'm gettin this error

> (...):Images.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)
>
> (...):Images.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()
>
> (...):Images.cpp:(.text$_ZN2cv6StringD1Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD1Ev]+0x11): undefined reference to cv::String::deallocate() ...

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which libraries have you linked? You are most probably missing some.

Comment: g++ -o main main.cpp \`pkg-config --cflags --libs`

Comment: @Frank but i've include the videoio.hpp (line 5)

Comment: @shawshank sorry, but i dont know about it :c i'm new to c++

Comment: How are you compiling your program?

Comment: @shawshank g++ main.cpp -o main

Comment: Do you know the path where `opencv` is installed?

Comment: @shawshank yeah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 14):

I faced the same issue with respect to opencv version `3.4.3`.

With reference [to this example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/videocapture_basic.cpp), I figured out that I was not including the `libopencv_videoio`. Once I added it to the project, the build was successful.

In opencv version 3, I think we also need to include the library `-lopencv_videoio` to use VideoCapture.

Comment: A wierd thing. "g++ -Wall -o test2 `pkg-config --libs opencv` test2.cpp" did not work after checking opencv.pc had opencv_videoio in it, which it did. However "g++ -Wall -o test2 test.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`" did work.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your code is not compiling is you are not giving the path of the libraries and the header files. Try compiling the code using the following command.

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I <path to opencv header files> -L <path to opencv libraries> -l<name of libraries>
```

A sample example if you are using linux is

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui
```

Here I am assuming your header file are in `/usr/local/include` and libraries are in `/usr/local/lib` and `lopencv_core` is the name of your library

Comment: But i compile codes with others opencv's files. Only this file the code not work. Anyway i'll try

Comment: Yeah, same error. If i delete `VideoCapture cap(0);` the code compiles.

Comment: What all libraries have you included while compiling your code?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after forking a Github project. I resolved it using these posts.
My problem was in the Makefile I forked, I had to replace these lines.
oldLine:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
```

newLine:

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

I hope it can help someone ;)

Comment: Dear sir thank you so much, your answer just saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

you probably missing opencv libs , try to add them to your project config file like

```
LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\opeencv4.1\\x86\\mingw\\bin \
    libopencv_core410 \
    libopencv_highgui410 \
    libopencv_imgcodecs410 \
    libopencv_imgproc410 \
    libopencv_features2d410 \
    libopencv_video410 \
    libopencv_videoio410 \
```